# Python - Multiple user types implementation in Django 2.2

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(2.2) in which I have to implement four types of users as `(1): Personal - Below 18 (2): Personal 18 or Above (3): Coach (4): Parent`, each user will share some basic fields like `First & Lat name, Email, Gender, Account type`  but also will have different permissions, dashboards and functions and need to provide different signup forms but one login form. Along with that I also need to use the `Email` as the username for this project.
what is a good and scalable approach? any resource or tutorial links will be appreciated.
and how can I utilize `django-allauth` in this scenario?

and here's how I was thinking to implement this:

```
class BaseUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_personal_above_18 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_personal_below_18 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_parent = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email + '/s account'


class PersonalAccountAbove18(BaseUser):
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(default=generate_cid())


class PersonalAccountBelow18(BaseUser):
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False)


class ParentAccount(BaseUser):
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(default=generate_cid())
```

The reason to use `customer_id` in each model is because later we need to connect different accounts, for example if someone wants to create an as `pERSONAL - BELOW 18` he will require to provide a `customer_id` of his `Parent` account.

Comment: Why would you need `BaseUser` as one to one field when you are inheriting from it?

Comment: Was a mistake, just removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if making an extra field in the `BaseUser` model for separating the accounts work but if it seems complex and you want to accommodate a whole bunch of customization for each then it does make sense to create a separate model for each.

If the latter is true then in theory, you should use a single `User` model and keep a one-to-one from the separate accounts to this model. And keep the common logics in the `User` model while keeping those specific to the account models in them.

The implementation you wrote has some issues:

- Your all individual `*Account*` models inherit from `BaseUser` and also has a one-to-one with it; this will cause all sorts of havocs down the line regarding field mappings and retrieval. `BaseUser` is a concrete model so only keep the one-to-one relation and inherit from `django.db.models.Model` e.g:

  ```
  class PersonalAccountAbove18(Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(BaseUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
  ```
- The `coutomer_id` field is not necessary as Django has an `id` (`AutoField`) that uniquely identifies each row so you can leverage that. Also as you have not used `primary_key` on the `customer_id` field so `id` field will be created anyways. If for some reason you need to have the `BigIntegerField` (because of scalability in the long run) you better make that the `primary_key` so the `id` field is not created (assuming `generate_cid()` returns unique values for the table each time):

  ```
  class PersonalAccountAbove18(Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(BaseUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
      customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, default=generate_cid)
  ```
- You were setting `default=generate_cid()` which means all the instances will have the same `default` as the default is being set at definition time. You need to drop the call to `generate_cid` (i.e. `default=generate_cid`) just like I did in the above point to make the evaluation when the field value is actually needed for an instance
- If you want to use permission related fields (`is_superuser`, `groups`, `user_permissions`) and associated logics in the `BaseUser` model, you also want to inherit from `PermissionsMixin` (`django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionsMixin`):

  ```
  class BaseUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
      ...
  ```
- You would also want to create a custom model manager to update `create_user`/`create_superuser` methods to use the `email` field for user creation instead of the `username` field. You can take inspiration from [here](https://heemayl.net/posts/django-custom-user-model-without-username-field-and-using-email-in-place-of-it/).
- It would make sense to rename the `UserBase` model as `User` to keep consistency with the Django procedures/methodologies.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I fixed some of the issues in child models, the `customer_id` will be the key by which I will connect different accounts  to each other e.g If a child want to create an account he will require the `customer_id` of his parent account. Can you put me any resource to learn about groups and permissions?

Comment: @AbdulRehman Start with the official doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#groups

Comment: Sure, I will do, but I still have issues related to this question.

Comment: @AbdulRehman If you feel you would be better served asking a new question, please do so. Putting multiple questions in a single one is frowned upon here, so please considert that. Also if you feel my answer does not cover your original queries, please say so; I'm happy to help further if you have a clear concise question. I don't want your upvote, I want to help you if you have a clear idea of what you want. Thanks.

Comment: here's the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59069679/7644562
take a look, please!