# Python - Create multiple user types and email as the username field in Django 2

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-2.0

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(2.2) in which I have to implement multiple types of users as:

1. Personal Account - below 18
2. Personal Account - above 18
3. Parent Account
4. Coach Account
5. Admin

along with that, I also need to use `email` as the `username` field for login/authentication.

The strategy I'm trying to use is to build a custom base model as `User` inherited from `AbstractBaseUser` and also created a custom `User Manager` to make the `email` as `username` but it's not working.

Here's my complete model code:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        now = timezone.now()
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            is_staff=is_staff,
            is_active=True,
            is_superuser=is_superuser,
            last_login=now,
            date_joined=now,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


def generate_cid():
    customer_number = "".join([random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(10)])
    return customer_number


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_personal_above_18 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_personal_below_18 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_parent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % self.pk

    def get_email(self):
        return self.email


class PersonalAccountAbove18(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                primary_key=True, related_name='profile')
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(default=generate_cid)


class PersonalAccountBelow18(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                primary_key=True, related_name='profile')
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False)


class ParentAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                primary_key=True, related_name='profile')
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(default=generate_cid)
```

I'm confused about my approach and even it's also return an error when I run `makemigrations` as:

> users.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
>       HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
>
> **Update:**
>   I removed the `PermissionMixin` and `related_name` attributes from child models and migrations are running now but it still require the `username` instead of `email`.

Answer (score 2):

The errors in `makemigrations`, and later (after dropping `PermissionsMixin`) requiring `username` instead of `email` for authentication are hints that you have not set your custom model as the *default* user model to be used by the Django `auth` app. As a result, Django is using the `auth.User` model as the default user model and your one being added to the project like any other model. So both of the user models exist simultaneously with the `auth.User` being the default/active one used for authentication purposes.

In essence, edit your `settings.py` to add the following:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<your_app>.User'
```

Now Django will use your customized `User` model instead of the one from `auth` app (the default) and the `auth.User` model will be dropped. The `auth` app uses the `get_user_model` (`django.contrib.auth.get_user_model`) function to get the currently active user model for the project which checks for `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`, and by default the rest of the system (e.g. the `admin` app) also checks for this setting to get the current user model. So as long as you're using the `auth` app the above should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

For using email as login, I recommend the `django-allauth` package. It takes care of all the heavy lifting and you can use it to login with email instead of username. Will Vincent has a write up on this at:

https://wsvincent.com/django-allauth-tutorial-custom-user-model/

Will also has a good write up on creating custom user models at:

https://wsvincent.com/django-custom-user-model-tutorial/

In short, he recommends subclassing `AbstractUser`. Here is an example from one of my projects where a user collects points throughout their journey on the site and I must record these points.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def user_id(self):
        return self.id.__str__()
```